# Lebesgue integration of conditional expectation

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, conditional-expectation

Alert: I have little to no measure theory knowledge.

Assume $x,y \sim_{i.i.d} \mathbb{P}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is Lebesgue measurable. For a function $f$ we have:
\begin{align}
E := \mathbb{E}[f(x,y) \ | \ x].
\end{align}
I encountered a statement which says integrating the above over $x$ will return $\mathbb{E}[f(x,y)].$ How does this work?

Comment: Now that you have  question about measure theory it is highly advisable to pick up some basic measure theory. If you ask a question about measure theory and say you have no knowledge of measure theory how is one supposed to answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

If there exists a PDF for your joint measure, let it be $\pi(X,Y)$ then,

$$E[f(X,Y)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(X,Y)\pi(X,Y)dxdy$$
Since $\pi(X,Y)=\pi_{Y|X}(Y|X)\pi_X(X)$ the above is equivalent to

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(X,Y)\pi_{Y|X}(Y|X)\pi_X(X)dxdy$$

Then by Fubinis Theorem,the above is equivalent to : 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(X,Y)\pi_{Y|X}(Y|X)\pi_X(X)dydx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\pi_X(X)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(X,Y)\pi_{Y|X}(Y|X)dydx$$

Recognizing that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(X,Y)\pi_{Y|X}(Y|X)dy=E[f(X,Y)|X]$

The above is equivalent to:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\pi_{X}(X)E[f(X,Y)|X]dx=E[E[f(X,Y)|X]$$ where the last expectation is taken over $X$.  Note this holds for the general case so it will hold for iid.

Comment: Oh, so do you think the statement 'taking integration over x' is not enough? I think as you state we also need the probability of X.

Comment: @independentvariable I believe so since the  statement is dealing with expectations then the integration is with respect to the  probability of X as the weights.

Comment: thank you! that's what I think.

Comment: @independentvariable If  we do the integration just over X. Then we  get the following:  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(X,Y)\pi_{Y|X}(Y|X)dydx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(X,Y)\pi_{Y}(Y)dydx$  which does not equal $E[f(X,Y)]$